# installing only .pyc (python compiled) with setuptools

Tags: python, setuptools

I want to run `python setup.py install` (the setup script uses setuptools), and I want only the .pyc files to be included in the resulting egg or directory. all .py files must not be present. How can I do this ?

Comment: Write a script reading the ZIP file and removing all unrelated files...that's a three liner.

Comment: @restrisiko: agreed, but maybe there's a standard setuptools method to do it, and if so is the case, I'd like to learn something new about the tools I am using.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

not with `install`, but a possibility is to run the following command

`python setup.py bdist_egg --exclude-source-files`

and install the resulting egg in dist with easy_install

`easy_install dist/eggname.egg`

Note that [according to the manual](http://peak.telecommunity.com/DevCenter/setuptools#install-run-easy-install-or-old-style-installation) `install` is nothing but a shortcut to easy_install use.

Comment: This will break with python3 because the bytecode files are in __pychache__ and the python interpreter will not look in there unless the source files exist according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11648547/1071236)

Comment: @giskou I tested, it works in Python 3. Since the name of generated pyc file matches the name of original py file, it can be located by the interpreter.