# How to run a Python project using __pycache__ folder?

Tags: python, python-3.x, compilation, cpython, pyc

I want to run a Pythonic project using Python compilation (`.pyc` or `__pycache__`). In order to do that in *Python2*, I haven't any problem.

---

Here is a simplified example in a *Python2* project:

- Project tree:

  ```
  test2
  ├── main.py
  └── subfolder
      ├── __init__.py
      └── sub.py
  ```
- Compile:

  ```
  python -m compileall test2
  ```
- Project tree after the compile:

  ```
  test2
  ├── main.py
  ├── main.pyc
  └── subfolder
      ├── __init__.py
      ├── __init__.pyc
      ├── sub.py
      └── sub.pyc
  ```
- As you can see, several `.pyc` manually generated. Now I can run this project using `main.pyc` as fine, which has a relation with the `sub.py`:

  ```
  python main.pyc
  ```

  Out:

  ```
  Hi
  Bye
  ```
- main.py content:

  ```
  from subfolder import sub

  print('Bye')
  ```
- sub.py content:

  ```
  print('Hi')
  ```

---

Now I want to retry this behavior in a *Python3* project.

Here is a simplified `asyncio` (available in *Python3*) project:

- Project tree:

  ```
  test3
  ├── main.py
  └── subfolder
      ├── __init__.py
      └── sub.py
  ```
- Compile:

  ```
  python3 -m compileall test3
  ```
- Project tree after the compile:

  ```
  test3
  ├── main.py
  ├── __pycache__
  │   └── main.cpython-36.pyc
  └── subfolder
      ├── __init__.py
      ├── __pycache__
      │   ├── __init__.cpython-36.pyc
      │   └── sub.cpython-36.pyc
      └── sub.py
  ```
- As you can see, `__pycache__` folders manually generated. But I cannot run this project using `main.cpython-36.pyc` which has a relation with `subfolder`:

  ```
  cd test3/__pycache__
  python3 main.cpython-36.pyc
  ```

  Out (I expected that produced the `Hi Bye` message):

  ```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "test3/main.py", line 2, in <module>
  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'subfolder'
  ```
- main.py content:

  ```
  import asyncio
  from subfolder import sub

  async def myCoroutine():
      print("Bye")

  def main():
      loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
      loop.run_until_complete(myCoroutine())
      loop.close()

  main()
  ```
- sub.py content:

  ```
  print('Hi')
  ```

---

## Question:

How can I run this project (above *Python3* project) using `__pycache__` folder?

Or

How can I run a *Python3* project with the relation between subfolders using python compilation?

---

[**NOTE**]:

- I cannot use the `python compileall` (*Python2* compile) in the above `Python3` project due to the `asyncio` method.
- My Python(s) version is *Python2.7* and *Python3.6*

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can enforce the same layout of pyc-files in the folders as in Python2 by using:

```
python3 -m compileall -b test3
```

The option [`-b`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/compileall.html#cmdoption-compileall-b) triggers the output of `pyc`-files to their legacy-locations (i.e. the same as in Python2).

After that you can once again use the compiled cache via:

```
python3 main.pyc
```

The way the loading of modules works since [PEP-3147](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3147/#flow-chart), it is impossible to use pyc-files from `__pycache__` folder in the way you intend: If there is no `*.py`-file, the content of the `__pycache__` is never looked-up. Here is the most important part of the workflow:

```
   import foo
     |
     |
     -- >  [foo.py exists?]  --- NO ----> [foo.pyc exists?]  -- NO --> [ImportError] 
            |                                     |
            |                                    YES
           YES                                    |--> [load foo.pyc]
            |
            |-> [look up in __pycache__]
```

That means, files from `__pycache__` are only looked up, when a corresponding `*.py`-file can be found.

---

Obviously, building python scripts with a Python version 3.X in this way and trying to run the resulting pyc-files with another Python version 3.Y will not work: Different Python versions need different pyc-files, this is the whole point behind [PEP-3147](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3147/#flow-chart).