# Unable to import .pyc file from current directory

Tags: python, python-3.x

In some code I have been writing, I import a personal module (from the directory I'm in). When I use Spyder IDE, it works fine. However, if I directly use the interpreter (For example: in terminal, writing `$python file.py`), I get an error saying that the module does not exist.

FYI: The personal module is in .pyc format

Whats going wrong?

Comment: see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11648440/python-does-not-detect-pyc-files

Comment: That solved the problem, but why is it that Spyder IDE can do it and not the standard interpreter?